# how to send two request with curl using the same headears and params

Tags: php, curl

How to send two request with curl using the same headears and params, only the url change
I dont want to duplicate the code two time

```
$url1 = "www.example1.com"
$url2 = "www.example2.com"
```

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => $config->url1 . '/api/v1/orders',
CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($body),
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not wrap all the common parts into a function?

Comment: hello, i finally wrap all  the common part inside a function, and it work nice

Answer (score 2):

You can put everything into a function and call that:

```
function get_orders($url)
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url . '/api/v1/orders',
        CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($body),
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $response;
}
```

Call with

```
$url1 = get_orders('https://example1.com');
$url2 = get_orders('https://example2.com');
```

Answer (score 2):

Kind of basic:

```
$urls[] = "https://www.example1.com";
$urls[] = "https://www.example2.com";

foreach ($urls as $url){
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url . '/api/v1/orders',
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($body),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
}
```

I see a function option was also answered! :) this one is with a loop.